# Why does this NSDate object display today's actual date in its UITableViewCell's text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

A timeStamp of my object is logging a date of `2011-07-26 21:01:43 +0000` but displays today's actual date of 'July 26, 2011` on its cell's text.

I'm trying to make a predicate to search for this date but I can't get it right.

I tried doing

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
NSPredicate *tempPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp = %@", today];
```

But this logs `today` as `2011-07-27 01:47:05 +0000` instead of what I want, which is `2011-07-26 21:01:43 +0000`.

Edit:

The NSLog is empty.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];     
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]; 
NSLog(@"timeStamp = %@", dateString);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: If you go to the home screen what is the date and time?

Comment: You're not making sense.  Do you want zulu time or your own time zone?  If you want your own time zone use NSDateFormatter to format the date, specifying time zone.

Comment: I want my own time, my home screen says July 26, 7;13PM

Comment: Then use NSDateFormatter, after setting it to your time zone.

Comment: I tried this but its crashing saying unrecognized selector sent to instance     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSFormatter alloc]init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

Comment: NSFormatter != NSDateFormatter

Comment: Please see my updated code, for some reason it is not logging anything.

Comment: Maybe you should tell the formatter what format you want it in?

Comment: well i just want it in the standard format, like `2011-07-26 21:01:43 +0000`